# Android application Apple sign-in failed with API_KEY_ANDROID_APP_BLOCKED Error

Tags: android, firebase, apple-sign-in, google-cloud-api-gateway

I have implanted Apple sign-in as a social login sign-in option to an Android application on mine. When I try the feature web view displays the following error.

```
    {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "API_KEY_ANDROID_APP_BLOCKED",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "consumer": "projects/736077706434",
          "service": "identitytoolkit.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

By looking at this error it seems like the issue is in one of the keys we use for this implementation. But I have check the 4 keys (Services ID, Apple team ID, Key ID, and Private key) that need to provide to the google cloud API config. There is no mismatch. There is a Return URL that need to provide in google cloud API side and in Apple Console side. This is also the same.

Another weird thing is even though it takes so long to load the Apple sign-in web view when I run the application using android studio I was able to sign in to the application. Above error is only visible on the application that I have uploaded to the Google Play internal test. But In both builds, it takes around 2min to load the Apple sign-in WebView. So there must be something going wrong.

Please let me know where should I look into fix this issue.